# Install PHP 5.5 on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, php-5.5

I have a Centos 7 server running apache 2.4.6 and php 5.4. I'm trying to install Magento 2 on my server for a client but am having issues.

I need to have PHP 5.5 or 5.6 installed on my server for Magento 2 to run. I cannot figure out how to upgrade to PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6.

I don't know the difference between the two versions, so I'll take whatever I can get working !

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the procedure for PHP 5.6.

I was able to upgrade PHP 5.4.16 on CENTOS7 to version 5.6.25 with these simple steps. Important to note that i used the Software Collection Repositories.

1- Install All these new packages:

- yum install centos-release-scl
- yum install rh-php56
- yum install rh-php56-php
- yum install rh-php56-php-pdo
- yum install rh-php56-php-devel
- yum install rh-php56-php-mysql
- yum install rh-php56-php-fpm

2- Make apache 2.4 use php-fpm

Edit that file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
Put that content:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

3- Reboot services to handle php-fpm:

- systemctl restart rh-php56-php-fpm
- systemctl restart httpd

4- Enabling rh-php56-php-fpm  service on boot time

- systemctl enable rh-php56-php-fpm
- systemctl enable httpd

5-  Create a symlink for the new php version.

- mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/phpOLD
- ln -s /opt/rh/rh-php56/root/bin/php /usr/bin/php

Comment: I also installed gd extension:
`yum install rh-php56-php-gd`

Comment: Good but symlinks and SetHandler look overkill to me, a lighter weight solution is to just rename some conf files under `/etc/httpd/conf*` as suggested in https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual/installation/php_55_installation.html

Comment: In addition to these packages, I need to install `mbstring`.  I imagine that this will vary for each users needs, but the important thing to note with each new package is that you have to restart `php-fpm` along with `apache` to see the modules take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your terminal:
`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7*.rpm epel-release-7*.rpm`

Then :
`sudo yum install php php-gd php-mysql php-mcrypt`

and you should have php 5.5

Comment: You need to enable the "remi-php55" repository to get it, before the yum install command: yum-config-manager --enable remi-php55

Comment: @RemiCollet Thanks for that :)

Comment: I ran all of these, including the command @RemiCollet said to run.. I then restarted httpd and when I run `php -v` it still says `PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27)`

Comment: "yum repolist" and "rpm -qa 'php\*'" will help

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure for PHP 7.3

I was able to upgrade PHP 5.4.16 on CENTOS7 to version 7.3.11 with these simple steps. Important to note that i used the Software Collection Repositories.

1- install this alone

```
yum install centos-release-scl
```

2- then run this

```
yum install rh-php73
yum install rh-php73-php
yum install rh-php73-php-pdo
yum install rh-php73-php-devel
yum install rh-php73-php-mysqlnd
yum install rh-php73-php-fpm
```

3- Edit that file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf Put that content:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

4- Reboot services to handle php-fpm:

```
systemctl restart rh-php73-php-fpm
systemctl restart httpd
```

5- Enabling rh-php73-php-fpm service on boot time

```
systemctl enable rh-php73-php-fpm 
systemctl enable httpd
```

6- Create a symlink for the new php version.

```
mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/phpOLD 
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-php73/root/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score -2):

*Steps (Use **sudo** only if required)*

**1) Remove OLD Apache**

```
sudo service httpd stop
sudo yum erase httpd httpd-tools apr apr-util
```

**2) Remove OLD PHP**

```
sudo yum remove php-*
```

**if it´s a clean installation start from here:**

**3) Install PHP 5.6 (Apache 2.4 will be automatically installed with this)**

```
sudo yum install php56
```

**4) Make sure all the required PHP extensions are installed**

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

**5) If not then install them using**

```
sudo yum install php56-xml php56-xmlrpc php56-soap php56-gd
```

**6) To list the other available php extensions**

```
yum search php56
```

**7) PHP 5.6 MySQL extension (Assume you have already installed MySQL)**

```
sudo yum install php56-mysqlnd
```

*(NOTE: it is not php56-mysql)*

**8) Start / Restart Apache**

```
sudo service httpd start
sudo service httpd restart
```

**9) Check the version**

```
php -v
httpd -v
```

Comment: Are you using any special repositories? Having only default and EPEL 7 the Package `php56` isn't available